# How can I handle "(The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI ...." error while trying to upgrade Angular 5 to 8?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular8

I try to upgrade Angular 7+. My version is Angular 5  now. Whatever I did, I could not handle  "AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests."  error

I wrote this commands in developer command prompt and thought I installed all dependencies and It should work, but not working.
What did I miss? I have .angular-cli file , It had converted to angular.json , I had converted manually but nothing works. Should I run additional commands after these commands?

```
npm install @angular/animations@latest @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest  --save       

npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/cli@latest @angular/language-service@latest --save-dev             
npm install core-js@latest zone.js@latest   --save                           
npm install @types/jasmine@latest @types/node@latest codelyzer@latest karma@latest karma-chrome-launcher@latest karma-cli@latest karma-jasmine@latest karma-jasmine-html-reporter@latest jasmine-core@latest jasmine-spec-reporter@latest protractor@latest tslint@latest --save-dev

npm install typescript@latest --save-dev                   

npm install rxjs@latest rxjs-compat@latest --save      

npm install rxjs-tslint@latest --save-dev    

npm install webpack@latest --save-dev
```

I have also run `npm audit fix`   after running commands above but nothing works.

Comment: what are the error you find out in your terminal window

Answer (score 0):

You try to upgrade angular 5 to 8 first 
you install node version as 12.3.1 in node site

```
rimraf node_modules

npm install -g npm

ng serve
```

you follow its upgrade to angular 5 to 8